# Open file in Ubuntu using html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ubuntu

```
<tr ng-repeat="transaction in transactionDetails">
                <td>{{ transaction.FromParty }}</td>
                <td>{{ transaction.CreatedState}}</td>
                <td><a href="/home/moulali/docker-compose.yml">Open file</a></td>
                <td>{{ transaction.Status }}</td>
            </tr>
```

This is some part of html code.Here I'm creating an hyperlink for "Open file" td and path is a file present in my hard disk. My os is ubuntu. So when I click an hyperlink it t should open a file in local hard drive.